# Unable to run exe file?

Tags: python, numpy, pyinstaller

I had created an exe file and its working fine in my system.

When I run this exe file on other system where Python is not installed, it throws an `unable to find imports numpy` error while running the script

Comment: It is a good idea to give following details - a) What is exactly the pyinstaller command (and config file) that you used to create the exe. That allows one to understand exact switches you have used. b) OS (Windows/Linux - which version) Platform 32bit/64 bit etc. Without that it is nearly impossible to understand what you are doing and what is the problem

Answer (score 0):

The conversion from python to exe might not have included all dependencies, that being the reason for no numpy package detected on the new system. Maybe try a different conversion method? Or see if the one you used is missing the dependencies?